# Swagger UI 3 Authorization header value getting issue in spring boot 3

Tags: spring, rest, java-17, spring-boot-3, swagger-3.0

In my application using Swagger3. In that not able to get the Authorization header. It shows the "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException" issue. I am using spring-boot-3, spring-6 and Java-17.

The issue got in console:

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Required request header 'Authorization' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

Controller Class:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/testHeader")
    public String testHeader(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization") String token){
        return token;
    }
}
```

Dependency(pom.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger3-check</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>swagger3-check</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error images for ref:
[image]
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: This error about what method does not have parameter. Could you show request or test which call this endpoint ?

Comment: Endpoint I used: http://localhost:8080/testHeader. For reference added error screenshot in above.